# Cabal Install trouble resolving dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm following this tutorial trying to set up a Haskell project: http://shuklan.com/haskell/lec10.html#/0/9

I've had this issue before with 'cabal install'.

I get the message below. I read to try 'rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal'. I tried that and 'cabal install' again, along with 'cabal new-build' but I still get the same message.

How can I fix this? I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.4. I can make and run .hs files and us ghci. I've never created a "file structure" or anything like that with other programming languages, so I'm not familiar with what's involved.

Thank you!!

````
Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-install
command or the legacy v1-install alias as new-style projects will become the
default in the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot
replicate a working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: FirstCabalInit-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: base (dependency of FirstCabalInit)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (conflict: FirstCabalInit =>
base==4.6.*)
[__1] rejecting: base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0, base-4.11.0.0, base-4.10.1.0,
base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0, base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0,
base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1, base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1,
base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0, base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0,
base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2, base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0,
base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2, base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from
non-upgradeable package requires installed instance)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: FirstCabalInit, base)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, FirstCabalInit ```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can find the following guide to build tools in Haskell useful:

- https://kowainik.github.io/posts/2018-06-21-haskell-build-tools

According the error message, it looks like in your `.cabal` file you have a line like

```
build-depends: base == 4.6.*
```

This version of the standard library `base` is very old, it corresponds to GHC-7.6, however, according to the error message, you have GHC-8.6.5 installed. Since `base` versions are bundled with GHC, you can't use `base` for GHC you didn't install. See the following list of matching `base` and GHC versions:

- https://wiki.haskell.org/Base_package

It looks like your error can be resolved by the following fix:

```
build-depends: base == 4.12.*
```

For the future, I can recommend using `ghcup` tool to manage GHC and `cabal-install` versions on macOS:

- https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/

Alternatively, you can use `stack` build tool, it manages GHC versions for you in a sandboxed location.

Comment: awesome thank you! looks like that worked. I'm not totally sure about what you mean about 'managing GHC'. In the error messages, the say to use new-install, but I still run into issues when I do that.

Comment: @poopsmith By managing GHC I mean the ability to install different versions of GHC, set the default GHC version, remove installed versions, see all installed versions, etc. If you have `cabal-install` version >= 3.0, then you can use `cabal build` command (`new-build` became the default in the 3.0 version). `new-build` is better in general and doesn't have some problems of the old build. But it doesn't solve all problems automatically.

Comment: Ok I understand. I've never really dealt or had to worry about things like versions, package/library managers, and different 'production' or 'larger project' -type issues for any programming language. Most of it has been plug n play, but I'd like to learn haskell and the ecosystem deeper, so thanks for helping!

Answer (score -3):

> *Famous "cabal hell".*

You're better use newest package manager https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/ .